# Покраска ячеек в google-spreadsheets при использовании нескольки условий

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Добрый день. Стоит задача: при выборе определнного значения в ячейке, окрашивать ее и еще несколько соседних ячеек в строке в определнный цвет. При том, таких действий должно быть несколько для разных ячеек. В частности, для ячеек во 2 и 11 столбцах. Для 2 столбца скрипт работает, при добавлении части скрипта для 11 столбца - скрипт не работает вообще. В чем причина и как с ней бороться? 
Собственно сам скрипт:

```
    function onOpen() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var entries = [{name : "Покрасить",functionName : "MakeMeHappy"}];
    sheet.addMenu("Скрипты", entries);
    };

function MakeMeHappy(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  if(range.getColumn() == 2){
    for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++){
  switch (data[i][0]){
    case "Низкий":
      range.offset(i,0,1,2).setBackgroundColor("#00CCFF");
      break;
    case "Средний":
      range.offset(i,0,1,2).setBackgroundColor("#FFFF00");
      break;
    case "Высокий":
      range.offset(i,0,1,2).setBackgroundColor("#FFAA00");
      break;
    case "Срочно":
      range.offset(i,0,1,2).setBackgroundColor("#FD6B6B");
      break;
    default: break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (range.getColumn() == 11)
    for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++){
      switch (data[i][0]){
        case "100%":
          range.offset(i,-8,1,3).setBackgroundColor("#A4FFAD");
          break;
        default: break;
      }
    }
};
```

P.S. С javascript работать только начинаю, потому пользовался найдеными шаблонами и своими ограниченными знаниями (уж совсем ограничеными). За качество кода - не обессудьте.

Answer (score 1):

Для условной закраски ячейки есть отличный инструмент "Условное форматирование", работает прекрасно и быстрее кода. Можете выбрать сколько угодно цветов. Инструмент интуитивный, довольно простой.

А так у вас кажется пропущен "{" в конце `if (range.getColumn() == 11)`